# Can I use FIR interpolator while modeling a DAC (Digital-to-Analogue converter) in 5G NR transmitter?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, lte

**Problem statement:**
I am explaining my concept on The DAC implementation in 5G NR using an example.
For a CBW=20 MHz, SCS=15 KHz, the sampling frequency= 30.72 MHz. After the time domain signal generation, the time domain sample can be represented as,

```
x(t)=[0.5 0.2 0.3 .....]  % [307200X1]  taking 10 ms of sample
```

After applying DAC of **zero order hold** with up-sampling rate 4, we will get the following,

```
x_DAC(t)=[0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.3 ...]  % [1228800X1]
```

**Remarks:** The energy in the side lobes are still high and this can cause low ACLR magnitude in practical 5G NR system. The reason of up-sampling is to accommodate the ACLR measurment.

**Reference solution:** In one of example in MATLAB [Reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/5g/ug/modeling-and-testing-an-nr-rf-transmitter.html), they are using FIR interpolation block (**No DAC block due to analog domain calculation**) for NR testing and measurement purpose.

**Query:** FIR interpolation block in MATLAB consists of low pass filter to suppress the images due to upsampling.

1. Do we really use an FIR interpolation block in practical 5G NR transmitter to increase the rejection between in-band and out-of-band channel?
2. To model the Matlab example in digital domain do I need to use a only DAC block or FIR interpolation block or DAC after FIR interpolation block right after the signal generation? How practical is this? (Note: simple Zero order hold DAC does not supress out of band signal that much.)

Comment: you never do ZOH upsampling. Why would you? That's bad. And at these low sampling rates, you could a) do proper upsampling both in accelerator/software as well as in converter hardware (that's actually how it's done) and b) you always need an analog anti-imaging filter, anyways, so why would you let your DAC be modeled as a ZOH interpolator?

Comment: To avoid explaining things in length and then finding out (the fourth time) that you just read ZOH for a completely different system and applied it here: Where does the idea to ZOH come from? Maybe I'm missing something (it's not the *worst* model for a DAC without incorporating the reconstruction filter, but then you need to model that as well).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for explaining. Just to clarify, do you mean anti-imaging filter is the FIR interpolation filter that I reference (MATLAB example) in my question? Thank you.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you mean in that comment, sorry. So, probably not :(